# Want to change dynamically 'onChange' attribute in input value with suffix depending on select value

Tags: javascript, jquery

My users want to create sub domain on my portal , first they have to write their  name of choice in input field then code checks availability of that name. If there is a single domain name, then it comes automatically by following code.

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="username"  AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF />
<span id="availability_status"></span></div> </p>
<script>/
$("#username").change(function(){
    var suffix = ".example.com"
    if(this.value.indexOf(suffix) !== 0 ){
        this.value = this.value + suffix;
    }
});
```

Now i want that user can select username as subdomain from more than one choice of domain name from drop down box.
For example like

```
<div>
    <label>Domain Name</label>
    <select name="s1">
        <option value="example.com">example.com</option>
        <option value="myexample.org">myexample.org </option>
<option value="myworld.org">myworld.org</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

if he selects second one - i.e myexample.com
and that in input box he will write the name for subdomain
example ----

```
sports
```

then in input box it should change like

```
sports.myexample.com
```

that is suffix

```
.myexample.com
```

should come dynamically after writing input value.

**EDIT:**

Assume that if

```
sports.myexample.com
```

is already taken then he has to select another domain name like

```
.myworld.com
```

by drop down and it should come like

```
sports.myworld.com
```

My Code for availability check is below :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()//When the dom is ready 
{
$("#username").change(function() 
{ //if theres a change in the username textbox

var username = $("#username").val();//Get the value in the username textbox

if(username.length > 3)//if the lenght greater than 3 characters
{
$("#availability_status").html('<img src="/loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Checking availability...');
//Add a loading image in the span id="availability_status"

$.ajax({  //Make the Ajax Request
    type: "POST",  
    url: “ajax-usernameapp.php",  //file name
    data: "username="+ username,  //data
    success: function(server_response){  
   
   $("#availability_status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request){ 

    if(server_response == '0')//if ajax_check_username.php return value "0"
    { 
    $("#availability_status").html('<img src="appavailable.png" align="absmiddle"> <font color="Green"> Available </font>  ');
    //add this image to the span with id "availability_status"
    }  
    else  if(server_response == '1')//if it returns "1"
    {  
     $("#availability_status").html('<img src="not_available.png" align="absmiddle"> <font color="red">Not Available </font>');
    }  
   
   });
   } 
   
  }); 

}
else
{

$("#availability_status").html('<font color="#cc0000"> not chosen</font>');
//if in case the username is less than or equal 3 characters only 
}



return false;
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: My suggestion would be to add text element near input tag, and whenever user select new option, just change that text element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use only *one* event handler for both *select* and *inputs* and whenever any one gets change get value of both elements and add same to your input box.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("#username , select[name=s1]").change(function() {
  var suffix = $("[name=s1]").val() //get select value
  var user_name = $("#username").val() //get textbox value
  if (user_name != "") {
    //get value of input before `.`
    var actual_name = user_name.split('.')[0]
    $("#username").val(actual_name + suffix); //add to input
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF />
<span id="availability_status"></span>

<div>
  <label>Domain Name</label>
  <select name="s1">
    <option value=".example.com">example.com</option>
    <option value=".myexample.org">myexample.org </option>
    <option value=".myworld.org">myworld.org</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: That works flawlessly. Thanks a lot. But one problem is there, when we select subdomain and write a name of choice , availability code confirms the status but on the same time if user selects another subdomain by drop down (but make no change in input box) than dynamically status change does not work. i tried slight changes in code like uses of on.change , 'keyup() and change() together', and others but no luck. please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you need to change input value only whenever user types something ?

Comment: i made an edit in my question that what i want to implement.

Comment: Your code only gets call for `username` input change ? where is select change code like i have added in my answer .

Comment: Thanks @Swatiji , it is working now. i was doing some mistakes. thanks again.